# Movie about deep-sea divers who encounter alien presence on ocean floor

Tags: identify-this-movie, science-fiction

In this movie, professional divers, or scientists, dive to a very deep portion of the ocean floor, perhaps the Marianas trench. I can't recall the purpose. There is storm and the divers lose contact with the surface. A military or other vessel can't reach them until the storm subsides. Strange things begin to happen on board the submerged craft.

That should be enough. I don't want to spoil the amazing ending. I've been incorrectly thinking for years it's "The Deep" but just discovered that is not the one I'm thinking of.

Comment: Sounds a lot like the book Sphere, I never saw the movie though.

Comment: The Deep is about a vacationing couple (Nick Nolte and Jaqueline Bisset) who stumble upon evidence of a wreck while vacationing in the Carribean, but there's intrigue because there's evidence of another, more recent wreck on the same site that was loaded up with medical morphine ampules, and the local drug lord (Lou Gossett Jr) wants it.

Comment: As you can see by the different almost perfectly matching answers, by not wanting to spoil the ending, you made it ambiguous. Maybe you could make use of spoiler tags next time?

Comment: Thanks for this question. I will watch all three mentioned great movies.

Comment: Just a piece of trivia:  The Abyss, Deep Star Six, and Leviathan all came out the same year - 1989

Answer (score 65, accepted):

The Abyss (1989) by James Cameron:

Comment: I thought it was Pacific Rim

Comment: Classic line: "Raise your hand if you think that was a Russian water tentacle..."

Comment: On a rainy day I watched this and Enemy At the Gates one after the other. It was really hard to untangle the nice rational self sacrificing hero from the cold vicious nazi sniper.... (Ed Harris plays both.)

Comment: An awesome film that left a lasting impression on cast and crew. Watch the DVD extras to find out how tough they had it. Yes, that includes the fluid breathing rat.

Comment: With the number of other movie with similar plot lines, I'm impressed you got it on the 1st shot.

Answer (score 25):

For what it's worth, your description almost nearly matches what happens in the movie [Sphere](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0120184/?ref_=fn_al_tt_1) as well.

Comment: Nice! Deep sea exploration, aliens, storm above. Been a long time since I've seen *Sphere* (1998) - were they near a deep trench too?

Comment: Don't forget [Liviathan](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0097737/?ref_=nv_sr_2) and [Deep Star Six](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0097179/?ref_=nv_sr_1)! This path is well-trodden.

Comment: Sphere is a great movie IMO, but this trailer is crap, not whatsisname's fault though.

Comment: @Mr.Kennedy - there was not a danger of sinking too deep (ie no trench) in *Sphere* (1998).  Great movie though, and it seems to fit the original question as well, mostly.

Answer (score 4):

First time on stack exchange here, and I'm pretty sure I know your movie!  It's called *Deep Star Six* (1989), and its about a deep sea military base which loses contact with its support ship due to a storm, and its inhabitants discover and battle an alien/undiscovered deep-sea creature.

I saw this movie as a kid, at least 15 years ago but I remember it pretty vividly. I'll have to watch it again to see how accurate my memory is :-)

[IMDb Storyline](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0097179/):

> The crew of an experimental underwater nuclear base are forced to struggle for their lives when their explorations disturb a creature who threatens to destroy their base.

Comment: I definitely know how a movie can leave an impression when you're a kid. "Omega Man" gave me the heebie-jeebies for years. Interestingly, it also had a Cold-War political theme.